# JPA different databases dialect

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I used mysql and oracle databases in the project, and used custom annotations to automatically switch the data source (using determineCurrentLookupKey()) on the corresponding method. Now how to switch the dialect of jap while switching the data source.

Please give pointers

```
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
#        primary-dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
#        secondary-dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    open-in-view: true
```

```
  mydatasource:
    boot:
     multiDatasourceOpen: true
     datasource[0]:
        dbName: oracle
        db-type: com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource
        driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.58.128:1521/ORCLCDB
        username: 
        password: 
        initial-size: 5
        min-idle: 10
        max-active: 20
        max-wait: 5000
```

```
    @Around("cut()")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {

        Signature signature = point.getSignature();
        MethodSignature methodSignature ;
        if (!(signature instanceof MethodSignature)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("error");
        }
        methodSignature = (MethodSignature) signature;
        Object target = point.getTarget();
        Method currentMethod = target.getClass().getMethod(methodSignature.getName(), methodSignature.getParameterTypes());
        MultiDataSource datasource = currentMethod.getAnnotation(MultiDataSource.class);
        if (datasource != null) {
            DynamicDataSource.setDataSourceDbName(datasource.name());
        } else {
            DynamicDataSource.setDataSourceDbName("main");
        }
        try {
            return point.proceed();
        } finally {
            DynamicDataSource.clearDataSourceDbName();
        }
    }
```

```
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface MultiDataSource {
    String name() default "main";
}
```

```
    @Override
    @MultiDataSource(name = "oracle")
    public Map<String,Object> queryAll(CmsCategoryQueryCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable){
        Page<CmsCategory> page = cmsCategoryRepository.findAll(
                (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
                        QueryHelp.getPredicate(root,criteria,criteriaBuilder),pageable);
        return PageUtil.toPage(page.map(cmsCategoryMapper::toDto));
    }
```